# Lyx error when creating nomenclature: "No file (%.nls."

Tags: lyx, nomenclature

I have a new installation of Lyx 2.0.7.  I'm trying to create a minimal nomenclature listing.  I've added a single "Nomenclature Entry..." and a single "List / TOC -> Nomenclature".  When I try to Update, I get

```
...
Running: pdflatex  "Arbiter.tex" > nul
19:35:11.984: Error while exporting format: pdf2
```

and checking the log file I find

```
...
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
No file Arbiter.nls.
(C:\Users\Stout\AppData\Local\Temp\lyx_tmpdir.Hp2560\lyx_tmpbuf2\Arbiter.aux) )
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, as a new user I can't hit answer... so...It appears to be a minor bug.

If you create a new document and add just one definition and one table, the file will not compile.  I'm not sure, but it appears makeindex is not called.

If you add a single printable letter, anything at all, the file will compile.  Interestingly, if you *delete* said printable item after compiling once, the file will *continue to compile correctly thereafter.*

The problem is only exhibited with a NEW document to which only nomenclature definitions and a table are added.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. When you have less than 100 reputation points you have to wait 8 hours before answering your own question. If you think this is a bug, you should report it at http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome (if it hasn't been reported already).

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a minor bug.

If you create a new document and add just one definition and one table, the file will not compile.  I'm not sure, but it appears makeindex is not called.

If you add a single printable letter, anything at all, the file will compile.  Interestingly, if you *delete* printable item the file will *continue to compile correctly* for a time.

The problem is only clearly exhibited with a NEW document to which only nomenclature definitions and a table are added.

Comment: If there's no output page, the `.nls` file is not written out, because the writing happens when TeX ships out a page.